# How to display the list of Weka Interfaces Not Necessarily

Tags: r, weka, rweka

I understand that we can perform Weka classifications and other data mining tasks in R using the RWeka package.

An example for creating a classifier is by using `make_Weka_classifier` with the following formats:

```
make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest")
make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/rules/JRip")
```

Now, we can find the list of interfaces using `list_Weka_interfaces()` but this does not show the other interfaces not in the registry just the two lines above. `list_Weka_interfaces()` shows those learners in the registry.

So, how do I find the list of the interfaces not necessarily in the interface registry?

Comment: I haven't used RWeka but my reading of the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/RWeka.pdf) is that the standard Weka learners etc. are already implemented as R functions (e.g. `JRip`) and you can use `make_Weka_classifier` (etc.) to create further R functions for additional Weka classifiers e.g. ones distributed as Weka packages. `list_Weka_interfaces()` shows the functions you've created by the latter method. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?